# The concept of a module resolution

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't understand the concept of a module resolution. I get that resolutions are supposed to represent the structure of the final (left res.) or first (right res.) module in an arbitarily long exact sequence consisting of modules of a specific variety (e.g. projective, free, flat). But the boundary maps/module homomorphisms are exact i.e. the composition of two consecutive maps always equals zero (im(k) is a subset of ker(k + 1)). So how do the modules other than the penultimate/second module relate to the module being represented by the resolution, since their elements are entirely mapped to the zero element of the represented module? The augmentation map only takes the second last/first module to the last/second modules, right?

(My apologies for such a stupid question.)

Comment: Look up *chain of syzygies* :-) A free resolution of a module gives it in terms of first a set of generators, then a set of relations among the generators, then a set of relations among those relations, et cetera. Exactly how many rounds you need to go is related to the cohomological dimension.

Comment: Thank you! That actually makes perfect sense. One more thing, sorry, ... but doesn't a syzygy and it's own syzgzy have to have the same dimension/rank since each basis element requires a coefficient? How does the resolution eventually terminate at zero? I should probably try to understand the Hilbert Syzygy Theorem, shouldn't I? Thanks again :)

Comment: I'm a bit rusty. IIRC whether it terminates or not depends on the ring (and the module you are resolving). It may go on forever. The point is that not every module can appear in every step. For example in a free resolution the kernel is a submodule of a free module, and is thus of a specific type. For example it won't have torsion. Thus it is possible that its resolution is shorter than that of the module we started with.

Comment: I see, so torsion gets factored out as you go further down the resolution so the higher-order relations become smaller and eventually terminate. Now I can see why resolutions are so useful.

Comment: Scratch what I said about torsion to the extent that it depends on the ring not having zero divisors whether a submodule of a free module may have torsion or not. Anyway, the kernels in a free resolution will/may come from a progressively selected class as the resolution goes on.